# Is list comprehension possible in this line of code of mine

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am still fairly new to Python, but I am getting more and more obsessed with shortening my code as much as possible, but I cannot figure out how to do that with this piece of code of mine. Is it possible to use list comprehension to shorten the following code at all? Also how do i edit my code so that the spaces and indentation show properly on stack overflow?

```
user_input = input("Please guess a number: ")
correct_number_list = [4,5,7,1]
    if user_input[0] in correct_number_list and user_input[1] in correct_number_list\
                        and user_input[2] in correct_number_list and user_input[3] in correct_number_list  :
                        in_range = True
                    else:
                        in_range = False
```

This is only a small portion of the code but it is hurting my eyes as I know there must be a better way to write this. In my original code I randomly generate 4 random numbers and store them in a list and have the user guess the numbers.
Any help or suggestions on how to shorten this code even if it does not relate to list comprehension will be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: You should focus on making it readable not shorter

Comment: List comprehensions are for *building* lists, not just writing code that *uses* a list.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that `user_input` is (at least) a 4-digit string. You need to convert each digit to an actual `int` first, as `correct_number_list` contains no strings. `'4'` and `4`, for example, are two different values.

Answer (score 6):

```py
in_range = all(x in correct_number_list for x in user_input)
```

Note that similar to your original code this does not correctly check the result because the player wins if they get one of the digits correct and use it for all digits of the number to guess.

Also, the value from `input()` is `str` so comparison with number is going to always be `False` if your generated number is a list of `int` such as if you do:

```
correct_number_list = [4,5,7,1]
```

Instead, you can sort the char in the strings then check that the strings match:

```py
rand_number = sorted(str(generate_number_4digits()))
guess = sorted(input('Enter 4 digit num: '))
win = guess == rand_number
```

Comment: `int(x) in correct_number_list`.